# sentry captureException doesnt show the entire error

Tags: next.js, sentry

I capture errors in a catch block using `captureException(error);` in my NextJS app.

However in Sentry it doesnt show the entire error message as I would see in the developer console. For example it only says: `AxiosError: Network Error` (see image below).

[image]

How can I make sure I get the entire error object?
For example, in the developer console I see this:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.hello.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`but this is not in sentry

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at on the screenshot is called a "breadcrumb". An event that happened during the user's session.

The `Access to XMLHttpRequest...` is a browser network error, and it's not exposed to the JS API, so you won't be able to capture it.

If you want to investigate what's available for your network errors, you can use `beforeBreadcrumb` callback, as detailed in https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/breadcrumbs/#customize-breadcrumbs